# Triggering a jquery action when the users mark a Checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

im very new in javascript and jquery. I have this checkbox:

```
<label for="editable">Editable </label><input name="editable" type="checkbox" id="edita"/>
```

And this jquery action:

```
$('#slickbox1').toggle(400); 
return false;
```

I want to execute that action when the checkbox is checked. Thanks!

Comment: You may want to re-do your html. If your INPUT has an ID of "edita", then your LABEL should have it's FOR be equal to "edita" as well. You have them different right now, so if you click on the label, it won't activate the checkbox.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try:

```
$('#edita').change(
function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $('#slickbox1').toggle(400);
    }
});
```

Although it's worth noting that running the `toggle()` method only when it's checked (assuming that it starts off un-checked) involves the user clicking the input *once* to show it, and then again to remove the check and *again* to re-check it so that it hides as a result of the `toggle()`.

It might be worth considering:

```
$('#edita').change(
function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
        // checked
        $('#slickbox1').show(400);
    }
    else {
        // un-checked
        $('#slickbox1').hide(400);
    }
});
```

Which *shows* `$('#slickbox1')` if the check-box is checked, and hides it if not,

**Or:**

```
$('#edita').change(
function() {
       $('#slickbox1').toggle(400);
});
```

Which toggles the `$('#slickbox1')` between `show()` and `hide()` when the `input` is checked and un-checked.

---

**Edited** to address the question raised by DomingoSL (the OP) in comments:

> ...can you please make an edit to see the procedure if now the triger is not a checkbox but a button?

There are two changes that need to be made to accommodate this:

1. a `button` has no `change` event, so it would have to use [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) instead, and
2. a `button` has no `:checked` (or equivalent) state, so the `if`/`else` becomes redundant.

One way of doing it, though, and I'm assuming your element names remain the same since you've posted no information to the contrary, is:

```
$('#edita').click(
function(){
    $('#slickbox1').toggle(400);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! alot! very goos answer, can you please make an edit to see the procedure if now the triger is not a checkbox but a button?

Comment: @DomingoSL: You would use `click` instead of `change`. Seriously, read the documentation: http://api.jquery.com/ there are tons of examples.

Comment: @DomingoSL: as @Felix notes, the jQuery docs have many examples. The reference for [`click()` is here](http://api.jquery.com/click/). I'm away from computer (until tomorrow morning, in the UK), but I'll add what help I can, as soon as I can if you need further help.